# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function whose return value I am assigning it to a variable and I am getting an error

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'. SQL Server

```
if @Miracle is null OR @Miracle   =''
select @Miracle  = TOP(1) M.MiracleName
FROM Miracle M where M.MiracelID = @MiracelID
```

how can I assign functions like TOP to a variable ??

Comment: `TOP` is not a function. It's a modifier clause that alters (modifies) the behaviour of the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need to move TOP 1 before your variable:

```
select TOP 1 @Miracle = M.MiracleName
...
```

Your aren't assigning TOP to a variable, but rather using TOP to tell SQL Server to only return a single row.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple as this.

```
if @Miracle is null OR @Miracle   =''
select TOP 1 @Miracle  =  M.MiracleName
FROM Miracle M where M.MiracelID = @MiracelID
```